# Font style on the second page of Sandbox Archive is broken for mobile web

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, footer

Compare the font style in the footer of the 1st and [the 2nd page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive?page=2&tab=Votes) of Sandbox Archive in mobile web:

> [image: 1]

> [image: 2]

Arrows in page selector are also affected.

Comment: It's because of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297160) which causes the entire rest of the page to get encapsulated into a code block on mobile. It has nothing to do with design, but a bug in the Markdown parser.

Comment: @animuson from the user point of view it’s obvious design bug. In the full web only single post is affected, could the same be done for the mobile one?

Comment: Well the obvious solution is to fix the parser so it doesn't affect either version at all, and only messes up the text of the post. That's not something the design team would do, though, because it's not something that can be fixed in just the HTML and CSS. It's a problem with the parser not removing elements properly, which is causing the structure of the page to get altered by user-contributed content.

Comment: **Because of me!!** Hehehehehe! (The answer that broke the formatting was *my* answer!)

Comment: @animuson I would recommend editing that answer to remove the code (or format it as code) and link a screenshot of how it used to work.

Comment: It's not just for that page, it can work for profile page too... [See this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354004/destructive-formatting-bug)