# Destructive formatting bug

Tags: discussion, bug, design

Bad formatting bug at smokedetector page when accessed through a linked-link. The link is as follows:

[meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/288114#288114]

[Click here to access the above link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/288114#288114)

Alternatively, it has been replicated on the [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/826559/cagliostro?tab=profile)

[image]

Captured on Mozilla Firefox (Recent Stable version).

AND

[image]

As captured on Google Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit).

***Touch to enlarge.***

Secondly, the page opens correctly if opened via

[meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive]

i.e. with the genuine format on all S.E. sites.

I speculate that this maybe because of the large amount of answers on that post. Awaiting discussion on this. Steps to reciprocate are simple. Just [click](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/288114#288114).

---

I have found the infinity stone.

Here is the source code:

[Click here and copy paste](https://tio.run/##nY7BCsIwGIPvfYp47cEyRB0y@hS7jR3s9suqpa1dp/Tpa91eQLyEJOSD@BQnZw@1DzlLcN5OV/uYcXMByS0BNOq44xxgEmgnPa8N3toYKMJLz1oZgrMmIbovg8VGbVBGZdx5ooBAdxoijX1X9XvGGh9INko2gxuLWdOvIgomNk5sxf/KGFAeXSCeoj6eqnPOHw)

To break my post thread. Copy paste the above as an answer.

---

It was found that wherever that specific code runs, the whole SE site redesigns itself (including the fonts).

Comment: I do not have any plugins running*

Comment: Replicated using responsive design on Chrome on Android.

Comment: @rene worth to mention that Nicael has been suspended at some point for abusing such bugs just to prove his point and try to force SE to fix the bugs.

Comment: This is a known and reoprted issue anyway: [Font style on the second page of Sandbox Archive is broken for mobile web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305286/289905).

Comment: @user289905 thanks, I have requested that the previous one be marked as duplicate considering more of a broad spectrum is found here,

Answer (score 2):

I clicked the link and nothing was destroyed. My browser did not crash.

The sandbox contains things that can break design, that's one of its original goals - to find such things, and report them.

If you're concerned about bad formatting and don't want to see it, don't view the sandbox.

If you reached the sandbox by mistake and want to get out of it, click the browser's back button.

If you see a post that "abuses" some design bug, like some posts in sandbox are doing, outside of the sandbox, try to flag it if possible. Otherwise you can also report in chat.

Comment: The thing is , it's just a small code...someone with malcious intentions can deface whole sites . The bug breaks the basic integrity of the webpage... it's not about the specific answer... secondly, i never said it crashes the browser

Comment: Someone with malcious intentions can also post spam, NSFW stuff, and tons of other things that will cause chaos if not removed. Abusing design bugs on purpose is no different, and should be treated in the same way: reporting the bad posts by flagging, and the mods will suspend the offender. It was done in the past already.

Comment: This sounds good but still a bug, thanks for your input

Comment: To properly report a bug title should be something like "<pre> can be abused to break design", with the body focusing on how to reproduce the issue, less on ringing the alarm bells. :)

Comment: thanks, I'll update...I was previously investigating the issue and now am certain

Comment: I have made a more contained bug^...look at the deleted answer

Comment: @Cagliostro that's not what I meant.